# Load CSV into site automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, csv

I am working on a website where I would like to search through a CSV for employee names. If that employee name is found it will popup an alert and give out information on that employee.

Right now I am using papa parse to parse the csv using this function.

```
<script src="./papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="choose" name="name" size="chars">


function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    name = document.getElementById("empname").value;
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    Papa.parse(file, {
    header: true,
    dynamicTyping: true,
    complete: function(results) {
    data = results;
    console.log(data);
     }
  });
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#csv-file").change(handleFileSelect);
});
```

I am able to open the developer console and see the data parsed in there no problem. The issue is I have to manually upload the file to the site using the choose file button as part of the input type "file". I'd like the CSV to load automatically when the site is opened.

I've done this in the past using PHP but with a database using mySQL. I can't wrap my head around how to do it with the CSV sitting in the same directory as the website.

Thanks!

Comment: if you need that CSV loaded automatically when you load the page, you need to upload it and move to the correct path with php first. Then do your js magic as you did.

Comment: What's in your console log right now? In general, I think your code should be working. (Control+Shift+i in chrome or FF)

Comment: My code does work and I can view the CSV in the console log but I have to manually add the file to the site. After looking into some php it looks like that may be my best bet. Put the info into a 2D array and use it to search through.